# Error passing pointer in QT

Tags: qt, pointers

In QT have the following code that starts a thread to send out commands. The thread takes a char * and int as arguments. In the "run" I use the pointer that is given by the constuctor. The code is:

```
MyThread::MyThread(char * payld, int payld_size)
{
    payload_size = payld_size;
    payload_p = payld;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    while(...)
    {
        sendCommand(payload_p, payload_size);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn´t work and my application crashes when I try to use thread.start(). But when I change it to:

```
MyThread::MyThread(char * payld, int payld_size)
{
    payload_size = payld_size;
    payload_p = payld;

    for(int i=0; i<payload_size; i++)
    {
        payload[i] =  payld[i];
    }
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    while(...)
    {
        sendCommand(payload, payload_size);
    }
}
```

The code does run and only crashes sometimes (looks pretty random to me). Can anybody Explain me why version one doesnt work and version two does? And any ideas on why the second code sometimes crashes? Could it be because the size of payload is not predefined (in the header file I defined it as

```
char payload[];
```

When I define it as:

```
char payload[10];
```

it seems to work better, but it is annoying to test since the crashes are pretty random.

Comment: What is `sendCommand` about? Are you changing your char* in other thread in the same time, i.e. reallocating it?

Comment: You are missing basic understanding of C++ data types and the way how it works with pointers. To make matter more complicated, you throw threading to the mix. Start with something much, much more simple, this is *not* something a newcomer to C++ can understand at once.

Comment: In Qt, you should be using QString everywhere and if you need to pass a `char*` somewhere to another API, then convert it using QString's toUtf8() member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of fiddling with `char*`, I would switch to [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) (since you're using Qt). It takes a bit of learning, but it's almost mandatory to get code working smoothly in this framework. Then declare

```
QString payload;
```

and depending on `sendCommand` implementation, use one of the member functions QString to get the char*, like `payload.toLatin1()`